# How to add space in the top of my bar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

How to add space in the top of my bar plot?
Here, i'm using seaborn and matplotlib to make the bar plot.

```
sns.set_style('darkgrid')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plots = sns.barplot(x = ['Positif', 'Negatif'], y = data['label'].value_counts(), palette=['#588b8b','#c8553d'])

for bar in plots.patches:
    plots.annotate(format(bar.get_height(), '.2f'), 
                   (bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2, 
                    bar.get_height()), ha='center', va='center',
                   size=12, xytext=(0, 8),
                   textcoords='offset points')
    
plt.xlabel("sentiment", size=12)
plt.ylabel("count", size=12)
plt.suptitle("Value Count\nPositive and Negative Label", size=16)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Change ylim? `plt.ylim(0,3000)`

Comment: With `plt.margins(y=0.1)` you can set a 10% margin.  In this case, `plt.margin` will only change the margin at the top, because the bottom is "sticky". This helps to make sure the code still works for new bar heights.